# How to speed up tesseract OCR

Tags: c#, .net, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to OCR a lot of documents(I mean in 300k + range a day). At the moment i'm using  [Tesseract wrapper for .NET](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract) and it's all good in quality but the speed is not good enough. The times i get for 20 tasks in parallel  scanning of a half page from the same pdf in average are 2,546 second per scan. The code im using:

```
using (var engine = new TesseractEngine(Tessdata, "eng", EngineMode.TesseractOnly))
        {
            Page page;
            page = engine.Process(image, srcRect);        
            var text = page.GetText();
            return Task.FromResult(text);
        }
```

The average time i get is after lowering the resolution of image by half and converting it to grayscale. Any ideas to speed up the process? I don't need to have text segmentated, just the text in one line. Should i maybe use something as [Matlab for c#?](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-function-from-c-client.html)

Comment: Do you create a new engine (call `new TesseractEngine`) for every page?

Comment: @GWigWam Yes, at the moment it's working like that. I'm pretty sure it doesn't support parallel use

Comment: You are correct, it does not support parallel use. However creating it is costly.

Comment: @GWigWam Okay, that got me thinking and i cheked the time of processing without creating engine, and it got me about 0.3~0.4 second less. It might help a little after some tweaking but is still not enough. Thanks anyway

Comment: that's still a 20% improvement, though I had hoped it would do more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently, you create a new `TesseractEngine` object for each page you scan. Creating the engine is costly because it reads the 'tessdata' files.

You say you have 20 parallel tasks running. Since the engine cannot process multiple pages at once you will need to create one engine per task and reuse it for all the pages that task processes. You can simply call `using (var page = Engine.Process(pix))` to process the next page with an existing engine.

Reusing the engine should significantly improve performance because you'll only have to create 20 engines instead of 300k.

Comment: I would not say 10% decrease in processing time is 'significant', however it depends

Comment: Great, saved me 1-2 seconds. better than none

Comment: Meaning, between 40% to 80% of the time? not bad!